# Find the first number in double array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this array:

```
000000000
000000000
00-2000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
00000-2000
000000000
```

What I want to do is go from left to right and in each line and find the first occurence of 
'-2'. I don't want to print any others.

I tried like this, but it doesn't work right

```
while ((g[p1][p2] != -2) && (p1 < 9) && (p2 < 9))
{
    if (p2 = 9) p1++;
    else p2++;
}
```

It's a 9x9 array and I am searching for the first -2 in it.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: So, you want the first instance of something, searching in row major order?

Comment: yes, the first instance of the number.

Comment: You have to show minimal compilable solution you tried.

Comment: I did, but it's hard. I want it to stop when it finds the element, not loop until the end of the array.

Comment: This calls for a `for` loop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the correct way to do this:

```
int p1, p2; //must be declared outside loop, otherwise they get deleted when it ends.
for(p1 = 0; p1 < 9; p1++)
    for(p2 = 0; p2 < 9; p2++)
        if(g[p1][p2] == -2) goto doneSearching;
doneSearching:
```

All you `goto` haters can now whine about how you should never ever use a `goto`. You're still wrong. Situations like this are one of the reasons the language has `goto` at all, and they are perfectly acceptable for use here.

If you are still resolute that you can never ever ever use a `goto`, you can disguse it as a `return` by moving it into a separate function, something like this:

```
template<typename E>
Pair<int, int> search(E[][] array, E target){
    for(int p1 = 0; p1 < sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array); p1++)
        for(int p2 = 0; p2 < sizeof(array[p1])/sizeof(*array[p1]);  p2++)
            if(target == array[p1][p2]) return Pair<int, int>(p1,p2);
}
```

Comment: What if I do something like this..
int gasitnr=0;
for (int aa=0;aa<=8;aa++)
for (int bb=0;bb<=8;bb++)
if ((g[aa][bb]==-2)&&(gasitnr==0)) {gasitnr=1;p1=aa;p2=bb;}

ugh, I'm new to this, don't know how to add code here.

Comment: Do not use `<=8`. Use `< 9`.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc No, that would be worse.

Comment: Why should I do like that if it means the same thing?

Comment: But basicly what I do is loop through all of it but save the positions in new variables.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Actually, it is not the same thing. The code in your comment is ugly, unreadable, and cludgy. Plus, it doesn't stop searching once it finds it, either; it still iterates through all the other items and checks them too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41122/discussion-between-ajmansfield-and-george-irimiciuc)

Comment: Goto?!? You're evil!!

Comment: @Velthune There are no cleaner options.

Answer (score 1):

Change: `if (p2 = 9) p1++;` to `if (p2 == 8) p1++;`

```
while ((g[p1][p2] != -2) && (p1 < 9) && (p2 < 9))
{
    if (p2 == 8) {
        p1++;
        p2=0;
    }
    else p2++;
}
```

Last position for p2 should be 8 if it starts with 0.

Comment: It still doesn't find me the first number.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc updated it, p2 has to end at 8 I guess and you also have to reset it when it reaches the end.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged C++ why don't you do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> rowStr;

    // Import your data however you need to, below is just for example
    rowStr.push_back("000000000");
    rowStr.push_back("000000000");
    rowStr.push_back("00-2000000");
    rowStr.push_back("000000000");
    rowStr.push_back("000000000");
    rowStr.push_back("000000000");
    rowStr.push_back("00000-2000");
    rowStr.push_back("000000000");

    std::string subString("-2");

    for (size_t r = 0; r < rowStr.size(); r++) {
        std::string binaryStr = rowStr.at(r);
        if (binaryStr.find(subString) != std::string::npos) {
            size_t c = binaryStr.find(subString);
            std::cout << "row = " << r << "; col = " << c << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is then:

```
row = 2; col = 2
row = 6; col = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((g[p1][p2] != -2) && (p1 < 9) && (p2 < 9))
{
    if (p2 == 8){
       p1++;
    }
    else p2++;
}
```

First of all, your code is wrong because you're using the `=` operator. The = operator is to ASSIGN a value to a variable and the operator you should use in this case is `==` which means compassion.

Also, you should be checking until 8, because an array in c++ starts from 0.